# How do I have a CSS classes priority be affected by what class it is "more closely" inside?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Up until just a few moments ago, I thought for sure that selector "distance" affected which css styles would be applied. Here's what I mean by distance:

```
.class-2 .target {
    background-color: green;
}

.class-1 .target {
    background-color: red;
}

<div class="class-1">
    <div class="class-2">
        <p class="target">Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I guess I expected that the `.target` element would have a green background color--since it seems like the `.class-2 .target` style is more specific--at least, target is more closely inside class-2 than class 1. But this is not the case. Apparently the only thing affecting the priority is the order they were declared in.

This seems really strange to me; I guess I assumed that CSS rules were applied from the outside in, or at least that that was a factor.

What do I do when I need a classes styles to be applied based on which class it is more closely inside. Is there any way to do this?

For example, in this JSFiddle, how would I get the backgrounds to be appropriately red and green colored? https://jsfiddle.net/emsca2ww/3/

In my specific case I need this because I am using a generally 12 column grid, and I need to (in some situations) set a 16 column grid context inside that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case you can use the child selector: `>`

https://jsfiddle.net/emsca2ww/7/

```
.class-2 > .target {
    background-color: green;
}

.class-1 > .target {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This only works for parent/child elements. Otherwise you would have to introduce more parent/child relationships if needed or rethink how you are using the selectors.

Selectors have specificity and cascade order. The above selectors have the same specificity because they are both composed of two classes. This falls back to cascade order. They exist in the same stylesheet as well, so the final priority rule is applied: order in the CSS document.

If you want `.class-2` to have higher priority than `.class-1`, you have to move the selector after it in the stylesheet:

```
.class-1 .target {
    background-color: green;
}

.class-2 .target {
    background-color: red;
}
```

However, this has nothing to do with the HTML itself. There is no selector for closeness between parents and children in the HTML document.  You could do something like:

```
.class-2 > * > .target
```

But this selector *only* works if `.target` is a grandchild.

Answer (score 0):

There is no distance priority in CSS, the only rules for priority are:

- the number of ids
- the number of classes, pseudo-classes
- the number of elements, pseudo-elements,
- the * selector

as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

To achieve what you want, you need to add some classes in your css:

```
<div class="foo class-1">
  <div class="foo class-2">
    <p class="target">Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>

.class-1 .target, .foo .class-1 .target, .foo .foo .class-1 .target {
  background-color: red;
}
.class-2 .target, .foo .class-2 .target, .foo .foo .class-2 .target {
  background-color: green;
}
```

By exemple. But if you have a lot of nesting, it could become a nightmare, and you should consider another way.